# advance table search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, search, full-text-search

In my app i have generated a scaffold called data and had filed the table with name, school, college, views, interest.
Now i want to add a search that if someone put NAME in the search bar, they should get all the names only as results, if someone had put college, they should get all the college only.

Am pretty new to rails, so i tried watching some tutorials, and had added this but this is not what i want

```
<%= form_tag data_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

**in controller**

```
  def index
    @data = Datum.where (["name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%"])
  end
```

This had added a search but not the type of search i had mentioned above.

Comment: Are you asking how to only return the name column?

Comment: @Dave Newton yes, what actually i want to achieve is that how can people search the column name instead of what is filled in column....for example i will not search a name  i will only type the column name as Name or Interest or College and the result should only return as therr respected column like if i searched NAME  i only want to return the name column

Comment: can you add your table code here

Answer (score 1):

I think, on controller

```
def index
  if params[:search].present?
    search_type = params[:search]
    @data=Datum.all.map(&search_type.to_sym)
  end
end
```

Note: I recommend change your `text_field_tag :search` to `dropdown (select_tag)`