# Search by column name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

Although I had asked this questions previously but hadn't solves it yet.
I have a student model with the column NAME, SCHOOLNAME, PARENTNAME etc.
What I want to do now is to make a search where when a user can search with the following columns name...
For example: if a user puts NAME in the search bar then he should get all the names of the students, if the user searched with the term SCHOOL NAME then he should get all the school name....
I tried a lot but hadn't achieved what I wanted
Help will be appreciated... Thanks

Sorry for not adding this question in a appropriate manner.

After adding @fbelanger solution in my project, actually nothing happened whatever I search it give me the same result...

*my controller*

```
class DataController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_datum, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /data
  # GET /data.json
  def index
    @data = Datum.all
    query = params[:query]
    Datum.all.map(&:query) if Datum::QUERIABLE.include?(query)
  end
  # GET /data/1
  # GET /data/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /data/new
  def new
    @datum = Datum.new
  end

  # GET /data/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /data
  # POST /data.json
  def create
    @datum = Datum.new(datum_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @datum.save
        format.html { redirect_to @datum, notice: 'Datum was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @datum }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @datum.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /data/1
  # PATCH/PUT /data/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @datum.update(datum_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @datum, notice: 'Datum was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @datum }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @datum.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /data/1
  # DELETE /data/1.json
  def destroy
    @datum.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to data_url, notice: 'Datum was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_datum
      @datum = Datum.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def datum_params
      params.require(:datum).permit(:name, :school, :hospital, :city, :food)
    end
end
```

*my model*

```
class Datum < ActiveRecord::Base
    QUERIABLE = %w(name city)

end
```

*my index*

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Data</h1>

<%= form_tag(data_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search here" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Hospital</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Food</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @data.each do |datum| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= datum.name %></td>
        <td><%= datum.school %></td>
        <td><%= datum.hospital %></td>
        <td><%= datum.city %></td>
        <td><%= datum.food %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', datum %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_datum_path(datum) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', datum, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Datum', new_datum_path %>
```

Comment: I remember I answered that before. Is it not work?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955019/advance-table-search-in-rails/40966091#40966091

Comment: ^ Wow same guy, same question, same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're in some controller action:

```
query = params[:query].underscore
Student.all.map(&:query) if Student::QUERIABLE.include?(query)
```

Then I would add a `QUERIABLE` constant to my `Student` model so that the user can not query anything other than what I've allowed.

```
QUERIABLE = %w(name school_name parent_name)
```

The reason no one is answering this question is because you're not asking for a technical solution to a problem, more like asking for the end result work.

Though you say you've "tried a lot", I highly doubt it since and you fail to provide any example of what you've tried so far and your question has not evolved at all in since the last time you posted.

## EDIT

The reason "nothing happens" is because you didn't to assign the array to a variable.

Furthermore, you would need to present the names using the array somehow, when your view is coupled to presenting records.

Comment: Hey @fbelanger sorry for not adding much brief... I have edited the question with your solution please have a look...

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by searching your query strings to see if the include your column name, using the `include?` method (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F)

Then you could run a `LIKE` search on you DB, which could look a few different ways depending on your DB ([What's the best way to include a LIKE clause in a Rails query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051062/whats-the-best-way-to-include-a-like-clause-in-a-rails-query))

To further @fbelanger's point, you should specifically say what you've tried, preferably by including a code example (even if it just uses fake things, like `class Foo...`).

I would also propose thinking of other more user friendly options, such as providing a dropdown of column choices *and* a search field, to make it easier for your end users to understand how to interact with the search form, and easier for your code to know which column to search.  (Just a suggestion).

~ Good luck

Comment: OP wants to return data from a column, not match records.

If someone puts "NAME" in search, all the `name`s should come up.

`LIKE` is for matching rows based of data, not a column name.